# Write to database only when a button is pressed

Tags: forms, datasource, axapta, unit-of-work, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a form with two datasources that are linked by using an outer join. It is written to the database by using Form Datasource Unit of Work framework.

As of now, the data gets written when moving from one datasource form control to another form datasource control. I want to only activate/write using Form Datasource Unit of Framework when a button is clicked.

Is there a way to prevent automated write function when moving from one Form Control to another?

Answer (score 1):

First have a look on [HowTo: Unit of work implementation for a Form](http://dynamicsaxposed.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/howto-unit-of-work-implementation-for-a-form/) to check you align with that. The official doc is [Change Group and Optional Record Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj129662.aspx).

The writes are issued because you are "leaving" a record, see [Event Method Sequences when Focus is Removed from a Record](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa628445.aspx).

This is the sequence when `validateWrite` returns true:

1. leaveRecord return true
2. validateWrite return true
3. writing
4. written
5. leaveRecord return true
6. leaveRecord return true (again)

This is the sequence when `validateWrite` returns false:

1. leaveRecord return true
2. validateWrite return false
3. leaveRecord return false

So you can override `validateWrite` to silently return false, when you do not want to save. Be sure to call `super()` when you *do* want to save!

Or you can call `leaveRecord` yourself to force a write:

```
if (record_ds.leaveRecord(true))
{}
```

When calling record_ds.leaveRecord(true) please observe that it may not save the record, e.g. if validation fails.  In that case leaveRecord will return false.

Observe that you are working "against" the standard working, this will make your form work differently than other forms.

Comment: Jan, thank you for answering.  Using Form Datasource Unit of Work, the write method never get called.  It only perform Writing() prior write action and Written() post write option.  There is no way to overwrite the actual write action since it is performed on the server.  Any further suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Another better update, a bit late. I had to know how `record_ds.leaveRecord(true)` was working.